# Robocopy Crashed trying to delete very long(1000+) subfolders WINDOWS

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy, delete-directory

I'm using the robocopy command

```
robocopy empty_dir super_subfoldered_folder /s /mir
rmdir empty_dir
rmdir super_subfoldered_folder
```

to delete the folders at once but during this command `robocopy.exe` stops working.
I have tried to delete from a path that starts at least 50 sub folders inside the main folder still crashes.

I've tried renaming them to "1" but windows doesn't let me past 100+ folders and there are at least 1000 more. Tried to create new partition- `subst j:` . rename some folders and delete the partition but this takes forever because of their number.
Tried `dir /x` and `del` the shortened name -> doesnt work.

Is there another way to delete those folders ?

Comment: After you've renamed the folders to "1" as deeply as possible, move the deepest "1" folder to the root of the drive.  Repeat as necessary.  If possible, script the procedure, since otherwise you'll be doing a great deal of typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File path in Windows goes through several layers before it gets to the actual file system driver. As a result there are two limits. 1) MAX_PATH (260) limitation introduced by the top-level API 2) 32K actually used by the file system. Since you already have that path, it is obviously within the limits of the file system. Try using path by adding "\\?\" to the front. This is an indicator that Win32 API should not parse the string but pass it directly to the file system (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). This will only work if the proces making the call is Unicode and 64-bit (on a 64-bit system). Otherwise the string must be converted and/or marshaled and you are back to the 260 limit.

Comment: OK, forgot to mention. Since you are passing the path directly to the file system driver there is no path manipulation. No current directory, no "." folders etc. You must pass the complete path.

Comment: Just tried the MOVE command. It accepts this syntax. I was able to move sub-trees using MOVE \\?\C:\complete\directory\path... C:\Temp

Comment: Robocopy automatically converts the paths it is given to \\?\ format.

Comment: The real issue is that I want to delete the folders not MOVE them, I actually found the Recycle Bin path and tried to MOVE the folders there but for some reason they don't appear in the bin and still remain.
Tried to add \\?\ in front of the file path in robocopy command to delete didn't work. I would really appreciate some code samples for DELETING.
robocopy empty_dir \\?\super_subfoldered_folder /s /mir
rmdir empty_dir
rmdir super_subfoldered_folder

Comment: Right. The MOVE would help you shorten the path and remove once the path is short enough. That helps in a one-time situation. I also wrote an example program for you. I will try to attach here as a new response.

Comment: @user3635759, I cannot reply here because this is closed. But you can get the sample program here: [RemoveLongPath.cpp](http://1drv.ms/1vFmvdQ).

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a `subdirectory depth limit` and it's not very deep.

You may get a better result by booting up a `Live Linux distro` on cd or USB, like Ubuntu, and using the GUI file manager to delete the tree.